# group a JSON object by properties and count and add count in each object?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

I have below an array of objects, need to get a count of the booking object, and the count needs to add in every object

```
const arr = [
{
    "ID" : 1,
    "Name":"ABC",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Rice and Flours"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 3,
          "item": "Oils"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 4,
          "item": "Oils"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 5,
          "item": "Rice and Flours"
        }


    ]
},
{
    "ID" : 2,
    "Name":"EFG",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals"
        }


    ]
},
{
    "ID" : 3,
    "Name":"IJK",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Spices And Nuts"
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Dairy Products"
        }


    ]
}


]
```

Code:-

```
const groupArray = (arr = []) => {
   // create map
   let map = new Map()
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
   
        for (let j = 0; j < arr[i].Bookings.length; j++) {
             
             const s = JSON.stringify(arr[i].Bookings[j]);
              if (!map.has(s)) {
                 map.set(s, {
                    ID:arr[i].ID,
                    BookingID: arr[i].Bookings[j].BookingID,
                    item: arr[i].Bookings[j].item,
                    count: 1,
                 });
              } else {
                 map.get(s).count++;
              }
        }
   
      
   }
   const res = Array.from(map.values())
   return res;
};
```

the above code is not working as expected and
I just want to group the JSON object by properties and count the number of identical occurrences.

the output should look like this −

```
const arr = [
{
    "ID" : 1,
    "Name":"ABC",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Rice and Flours",
          "Count": 2
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals",
          "Count": 1
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 3,
          "item": "Oils",
          "Count": 2
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 4,
          "item": "Oils",
          "Count": 2
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 5,
          "item": "Rice and Flours"
          "Count": 2
        }


    ]
},
{
    "ID" : 2,
    "Name":"EFG",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals"
          "Count": 2
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Pulses/Dals"
          "Count": 2
        }


    ]
},
{
    "ID" : 3,
    "Name":"IJK",
    "Bookings":[
        {
          "BookingID": 1,
          "item": "Spices And Nuts",
          "Count": 1
        },
        {
          "BookingID": 2,
          "item": "Dairy Products",
          "Count": 1
        }


    ]
}


]
```

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript (or TypeScript) source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could take an object with a combined key of `Name` and `item` and collect the objects and update the count for each group.

```js
const
    data = [{ ID: 1, Name: "ABC", Bookings: [{ BookingID: 1, item: "Rice and Flours" }, { BookingID: 2, item: "Pulses/Dals" }, { BookingID: 3, item: "Oils" }, { BookingID: 4, item: "Oils" }, { BookingID: 5, item: "Rice and Flours" }] }, { ID: 2, Name: "EFG", Bookings: [{ BookingID: 1, item: "Pulses/Dals" }, { BookingID: 2, item: "Pulses/Dals" }] }, { ID: 3, Name: "IJK", Bookings: [{ BookingID: 1, item: "Spices And Nuts" }, { BookingID: 2, item: "Dairy Products" }] }],
    counts = {},
    result = data.map(({ Bookings, ...o }) => ({ ...o, Bookings: Bookings.map(booking => {
        const
            key = [o.Name, booking.item].join('|'),
            object = { ...booking, Count: 0 },
            target = counts[key] ??= [];

        target.push(object);
        target.forEach(q => q.Count = target.length);
        return object;
    }) }));
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```